# Computer vision: Regarding a line through origin in camera coordinate

Tags: camera, line, coordinate, vision

I've a question regarding a line in camera coordinate.

Suppose the pixel/screen coordinate of a point is `(u,v)`. And the camera coordinate
(coordinate system relative to camera) of `(u,v)` is `(p,q,r)` where `(u,v)` is given and a
 line `L` goes through the point `(0,0,0)`  [origin camera location] and `(p,q,r)` where `r` is
 given. Is it possible to find `(p,q)`?

I know that the parametric equation of a line is:

`(x-a, y-b, z-c)= t(x_0, y_0, z_0)`

But I know only `(a,b,c)`  which is `(0,0,0)` and `z_0` which is `r`. Can anyone kindly tell me if it is possible to find 
the value of `(p,q)`? Can I use `(u,v)` in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible until you have more information about what something like `(u, v)` represents.  Think of it this way.  Suppose you claimed you could figure it out just based on `(u, v)` and `r`.  Now, what if I just relabeled your pixels?  A pixel doesn't have to represent any specific distance, so if I said (125, 100) was (250, 200) instead, that would make sense too. Suppose I just swap in a higher resolution chip for a lower resolution chip.

To actually recover `(p, q)`, you'd have to know what physical distance a pixel corresponds to.  You'd also have to know whether the pinhole in your camera model is (0,0) in your pixel reference frame, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

So if I know pixel size and know that if the pinhole is located at `(0,0)` can i then find
`(p,q)`? What other factors do I need know?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for not understanding but you mentioned two factors. 1) what physical distance each pixel represents and 2) whether pinhole is located at `(0,0)` What other factors do I need to know to use the parametric equation of the line given above? Is it possible to mention them all? Again thanks for your help.

Comment: That's it.  If you know that points with coordinates `(0, 0, z)` project to `(0, 0)` (or `(x, y)` or whatever), and you also know the physical distance a pixel represents, you'll be able to find `(p, q)`.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I just like to make sure. Are you saying that the camera location `(0,0,0)`, screen/pixel plane point `(0,0,z)` and the projected point `(p,q,r)` all
collinear?